# Connection pool is closed using Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I have a little web app which serves data from a Mongo database. I have configured 2 cron jobs (through Heroku scheduler) to run everyday and manipulate a remote db. The problem is that I need those jobs to conclude and not keep running after finishing, that means closing my connection, otherwhise my function keeps running.

When I call `mongoose.disconnect()` in one of my files I get `Mongo error: Connection pool closed`.

This is the problematic file:

```
require('dotenv').config();
const malagaCulturaScrapper = require("../scrappers/malagaCultura");
const Event = require("../schemas/eventSchema");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

(async () => {
    try {
        await mongoose.connect((process.env.DEV_MODE === "true") ? process.env.SAMPLEDB_URL:process.env.DATABASE_URL, {
            useNewUrlParser: true,
            useUnifiedTopology: true
        })
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('Error: ' + err)
    }
})()

const scrapeAndSave = async() =>{
    await Event.deleteMany({}).exec();
    await malagaCulturaScrapper.malagaCulturaScrapper();
    mongoose.disconnect();
}

scrapeAndSave();
```

Which calls this function:

```
const malagaCulturaScrapper = async() =>{
        await scrapeIt("https://malagadecultura.com/agenda/", {
            events: {
                listItem: "article",
                data: {
                    title: "h4",
                    time: ".mec-event-time",
                    date: {
                        closest: "li",
                        attr: "id"                        
                    },
                    event_img: {
                        selector: ".attachment-thumbnail",
                        attr: "src"
                    },
                    event_link:{
                        selector: "h4 a",
                        attr: "href",
                    },
                    location: ".mec-event-loc-place",
                }
        }
        }).then(({ data, response }) => {

            for(const index in data.events){
                let newEvent = new Event({
                    _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
                    title: data.events[index].title,
                    dateTime: createDateObject(data.events[index].date.substring(59), data.events[index].time),
                    event_img: data.events[index].event_img,
                    event_link: data.events[index].event_link,
                    location: data.events[index].location,
                })
                Event.addEvents(newEvent);
            }
        })

}
```

And this is my adding function on the schema:

```
Event.addEvents = async(newEvent) => {
    await Event.findOne({
        location: newEvent.location || {
            '$regex': newEvent.location, $options: 'i',
        },
        dateTime: { $in: newEvent.dateTime }
    }, (err, event) => {
        if(err) throw err;
        if (!event && !helpers.isPastEvent(newEvent.dateTime[0], Date.now()) && new Date(newEvent.dateTime[0]).getFullYear() === new Date(Date.now()).getFullYear()) {
            newEvent.save((err) => {
                if (err) throw err;
            })
        } 
    })
}
```

Lastly, the stacktrace I get when running the file:

```
/home/roma/Escritorio/Programming-projects/mlg-events/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:19
            throw error;
            ^

MongoError: connection pool closed
    at ConnectionPool.close (/home/roma/Escritorio/Programming-projects/mlg-events/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connection_pool.js:300:34)
    at Server.destroy (/home/roma/Escritorio/Programming-projects/mlg-events/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/sdam/server.js:213:17)
    at destroyServer (/home/roma/Escritorio/Programming-projects/mlg-events/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/sdam/topology.js:806:10)
    at eachAsync (/home/roma/Escritorio/Programming-projects/mlg-events/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/sdam/topology.js:353:25)
    at eachAsync (/home/roma/Escritorio/Programming-projects/mlg-events/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/utils.js:131:5)
    at s.sessionPool.endAllPooledSessions (/home/roma/Escritorio/Programming-projects/mlg-events/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/sdam/topology.js:351:7)
    at topology.endSessions (/home/roma/Escritorio/Programming-projects/mlg-events/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/sessions.js:592:13)
    at command (/home/roma/Escritorio/Programming-projects/mlg-events/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/sdam/topology.js:501:45)
    at cb (/home/roma/Escritorio/Programming-projects/mlg-events/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/sdam/topology.js:681:26)
    at fn (/home/roma/Escritorio/Programming-projects/mlg-events/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connection_pool.js:350:13)
    at Object.handleOperationResult [as cb] (/home/roma/Escritorio/Programming-projects/mlg-events/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/sdam/server.js:558:5)
    at Connection.write (/home/roma/Escritorio/Programming-projects/mlg-events/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connection.js:378:26)
    at _command (/home/roma/Escritorio/Programming-projects/mlg-events/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/wireprotocol/command.js:120:10)
    at Object.command (/home/roma/Escritorio/Programming-projects/mlg-events/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/wireprotocol/command.js:28:5)
    at Connection.command (/home/roma/Escritorio/Programming-projects/mlg-events/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connection.js:171:8)
    at s.pool.withConnection (/home/roma/Escritorio/Programming-projects/mlg-events/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/sdam/server.js:285:12)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at /home/roma/Escritorio/Programming-projects/mlg-events/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:4844:13
    at /home/roma/Escritorio/Programming-projects/mlg-events/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:16:11
    at /home/roma/Escritorio/Programming-projects/mlg-events/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:4865:21
    at (anonymous function).call (/home/roma/Escritorio/Programming-projects/mlg-events/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:4411:18)
    at Immediate.Query.base.findOne.call (/home/roma/Escritorio/Programming-projects/mlg-events/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:2145:7)
    at Immediate.<anonymous> (/home/roma/Escritorio/Programming-projects/mlg-events/node_modules/mquery/lib/utils.js:116:16)
    at runCallback (timers.js:705:18)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:676:5)
    at processImmediate (timers.js:658:5)
```

I would really appreciate any guidance or help on the subject. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The example code has `mongoose.connection.close()`. Have you tried `await mongoose.disconnect()` as well?

Comment: Just tried, same result, weird thing since I have another file which is for sending daily mails which uses a connection to the db and closes fine. My guess is something is happening in my scrapping or event saving function. Because leaving deleteMany() alone won't cause the error.

Comment: This is likely caused by what appears to be a long running process. In time, TCP times out and the connection is closed.  Use the `keepAlive` option in connection settings object to fix this.

Comment: Oh yeah, you're mixing callbacks and async in addEvents, and also not waiting for it in malagaCulturaScrapper

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code is trying to disconnect before the queries have completed.

Use the Promise API to mongoose by not supplying any callback functions and make sure you `await` promises so the `disconnect` run's after everything has completed.

```
const malagaCulturaScrapper = async() =>{
    const { data, response } = await scrapeIt("https://malagadecultura.com/agenda/", {
         ...eventsInfo
    })
    for(const index in data.events){
        let newEvent = new Event({
            _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
            title: data.events[index].title,
            dateTime: createDateObject(data.events[index].date.substring(59), data.events[index].time),
            event_img: data.events[index].event_img,
            event_link: data.events[index].event_link,
            location: data.events[index].location,
        })
        await Event.addEvents(newEvent);
    }
}
```

```
Event.addEvents = async(newEvent) => {
    const event = await Event.findOne({
        location: newEvent.location || {
            '$regex': newEvent.location, $options: 'i',
        },
        dateTime: { $in: newEvent.dateTime }
    })

    if (!event && !helpers.isPastEvent(newEvent.dateTime[0], Date.now()) && new Date(newEvent.dateTime[0]).getFullYear() === new Date(Date.now()).getFullYear()) {
        await newEvent.save()
    })
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, now is working! But, a question, why callbacks kind of interferes with promises? I usually get things quickly but I'm having a hard time understanding asynchronous javascript. Thanks again

Comment: They don't interfere as such, but mixing the two will make code more confusing than just using one or the other, and nested callbacks are already confusing enough. The reason `async`/`await` was introduced was to allow async/promise code to be laid out more like people write synchronous code. Promises also provide much more reliable error handling.

Comment: If you hang around here you'll notice there's various forms [of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) every day.  Even this question is essentially the same thing, how to wait for async code to complete.  Promises with async/await made this a lot easier code.